# openshift importimage error: Import failed (InternalError): Internal error occurred: unknown blob

Tags: openshift

I want to import an image from my local nexus repository into one of my projects in openshift
I have used this command:

oc import-image coolstore/turbine-server:1.0.27 --from 192.168.96.213:8180/siamaksade/turbine-server:1.0.27 --insecure -n coolstore --confirm

but the result was:

error: tag 1.0.27 failed: Internal error occurred: unknown blob
imagestream.image.openshift.io/turbine-server imported with errors

Name:           turbine-server
Namespace:      coolstore
Created:        Less than a second ago
Labels:         
Annotations:        openshift.io/image.dockerRepositoryCheck=2019-11-10T08:55:35Z
Docker Pull Spec:   docker-registry.default.svc:5000/coolstore/turbine-server
Image Lookup:       local=false
Unique Images:      0
Tags:           1

1.0.27
  tagged from 192.168.96.213:8180/siamaksade/turbine-server:1.0.27
    will use insecure HTTPS or HTTP connections

! error: Import failed (InternalError): Internal error occurred: unknown blob
      Less than a second ago